# Problem in my stopwatch with Thread Sleep

Tags: c#

I wanted to make a percentage counter that will increase by 1 in 0.1 seconds, but it turns out that the program slows down completely and does not display the counter but how it became 100%

```
for (double percent = 1; percent <= 100; percent++)
{
    label5.Text = percent.ToString() + "%";
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` lets the thread that's rendering your GUI sleep and do nothing. there's just no CPU time for your form to display anything until the loop is finished.

Comment: If you are an amateur, and you would like a solution with minimal learning investment, putting an `Application.DoEvents();` after changing the label is a quick and dirty fix. If you are a professional, spending some time [learning](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) about async/await will be a time well spent.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the UI is not doing anything until the event handler is finished. Try this instead

```cs
await Task.Delay(100);
```

You also will have to add the `async` keyword to the method doing this call. Something like this:

```cs
private async void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

See also: [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) (Microsoft Docs)

The linked doc says:

> The await keyword is where the magic happens. It yields control to the caller of the method that performed await, and it ultimately allows a UI to be responsive or a service to be elastic.

---

A different approach is to use a timer. Make sure to use a timer adapted to the kind of UI you have. E.g., if you are working with winforms, use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. You will have to add it a `Tick` event handler. At each tick this handler will be called on the UI thread. Update the label there (not in a loop this time!). Between two ticks, the UI will be responsive.

See also: [How to: Run Procedures at Set Intervals with the Windows Forms Timer Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).
                *There is a nice example doing exactly what you need.*